# how to copy data from one file to another in capl

Tags: file, copy, capl

Here I am trying to copy data from one file into another file.Here files are successfully opening and closing but data is not getting copied into the file. The source file and destination file are in the same location. Also the data getting copied into the file is in string format ,how can i convert that into hex value before copying into the file.

```
variables
{

    dword fHandler;
    dword handle;
    char DataRecordBuf[15000][50];
    byte recordData[15000][50];
    byte dataRecordLen;
    byte dataRecordTyp;    
}

on start
{

    dword i = 0;
    dword len = 0;
    fHandler = openFileRead("TestFile.hex",0);

    if(fHandler == 0)
    {
        write("%s",fHandler);
        write("Error occured while opening file\n");        
    }
    else
    {
        write("File opened successfully for reading\n");
        while(fileGetStringSZ(DataRecordBuf[i++],elCount(DataRecordBuf),fHandler) != 0);
        len = i;
        i = 0;
        handle = openFileWrite("MyCaplData.txt",2);
        write("File opened successfully for writing\n");
        while(len--)
        {
            filePutString(DataRecordBuf[i++],elCount(DataRecordBuf),handle);
        }
        fileClose(handle);
        write("File Closed Successfully\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is anything at all copied?

Comment: No. whenever i run the code the destination file remains blank always

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read an write binary data, you should use

```
openFileRead("TestFile.hex", 1);
```

and

```
openFileWrite("MyCaplData.txt", 3);
```

This will open the files in binary mode and not in ASCII mode.

You should then use `fileGetBinaryBlock` and `fileWriteBinaryBlock` to read and write the data.

Comment: ,I want the data in ASCII mode not in binary mode. Any APIs available in CAPL to convert data from string to ascii or to read data from file directly in ascii mode

Comment: Maybe you could post some examples of what is stored in the files and how you expect the output to be. Now I am confused by what you mean by _converting from string to ascii_